# Changing chunk size in MongoDB gridfs using mongofiles utility

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

We are using MongoDB 3.4 and we are trying to store bulk videos in MongoDB GridFS.
We used **mongofiles** command line utility to load video to the gridfs.

But it chunks the video file with default chunk size 255kb.

Is there any way to change chunk size in the configuration file or while loading a video using **mongofiles**?

Thanks,
Hari

Answer (score 0):

No!
When you use Java, PHP,.. driver you can change that. But `mongofiles` program don't support it.

In the Java driver you'd call [setChunkSize](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.7.0/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFSInputFile.html#setChunkSize%28long%29) on [GridFSInputFile](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.7.0/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFSInputFile.html).

Comment: It's quite simple task to make f.ex. PHP script to import files to collection... Then you can choose yourself what size you want to use.

Comment: Thank you Jussi. I used php script and it is working fine.

Comment: Sorry, bad choice of word! Please mark my answer as "correct answer".